# What is the way to handle a user preferences file in Flex3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, user-preferences

I need a way to handle user preferences in a file. Of course, users can update their preferences.
What is the best way to do that ?
.ini file or .xml file ... 
Any snippet to start with ?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most flex-like way of doing this would be to use a local shared object.  You can save basic actionscript objects to the users system and access them at any time from any swf loaded from your domain.  many games use this for their save feature and many websites use this as a cookie store and/or user preferences store.

docs and example - http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects